# Golang io.copy not copying entire data

Tags: go, google-cloud-storage

I have small code which reads 100 MB file from Google cloud storage and then return output.

Code works fine for 1MB file but fails for 100 mb file.

Below is the code which is not working

```
rc, err := client.Bucket("mabucket").Object(gcpurl).NewReader(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)

        return
    }
    defer rc.Close()

    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(int(rc.Size())))
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=2592000")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", rc.ContentType())

    spew.Dump(rc.ContentType())

    if rc.ContentType() == "audio/wav" || rc.ContentType() == "audio/wave" {
        w.Header().Set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")

        tilrange := rc.Size() - 1
        newRangeString := "bytes 0-" + strconv.Itoa(int(tilrange)) + "/" + strconv.Itoa(int(rc.Size()))
        w.Header().Set("Content-Range", newRangeString)
        w.WriteHeader(206)

    }

    //spew.Dump(rc.Attrs)

    io.Copy(w, rc)
```

I have written another code which is able to download same file and create a local file of 100 mb.
this time I am using **ioutil.ReadAll**. what can be problem with **io.copy** when receiving large date from GCP?

```
func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, _ := storage.NewClient(ctx)

    
    data, err := downloadFile(client, "mabucket", "606ff2b71a916907409a953f/606ff2ed1a916907409a9540/60a38a967b291f7b44488824/123/audio/210415164000M29713363.wav")
    //210415164000M29713363.wav

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Cannot read object: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Object contents: %d\n", len(data))

    f, err := os.Create("a.wav")
    check(err)
    defer f.Close()

    n2, err := f.Write(data)
    check(err)
    fmt.Printf("wrote %d bytes\n", n2)
}

// downloadFile downloads an object.
func downloadFile(client *storage.Client, bucket, object string) ([]byte, error) {
    // [START download_file]
    ctx := context.Background()

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, time.Second*50)
    defer cancel()
    rc, err := client.Bucket(bucket).Object(object).NewReader(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer rc.Close()

    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(rc)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, nil
    // [END download_file]
}
```

Comment: [io.Copy](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) returns an error value. Always check errors - and log them if non-nil.

Comment: @colm.anseo you are right , it is giving (*net.OpError)(0xc0003302d0)(write tcp [::1]:80->[::1]:63014: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.). ioutil.copyall works. can this be error from GCP golang library?

Comment: It could be the platform you're running your app terminates the request after a certain amount of time, e.g. 1 minute, and the transfer of 100MB doesn't complete in that time. When writing to file, it may be finishing before the deadline.

Comment: icza , I am using windows 10 locally, for server I am using google cloud run , there error is "Response size was too large. Please consider reducing response size."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

io.copy was trying to copy the details but OS was not allowing it. it was throwing error as  (*net.OpError)(0xc0003302d0)(write tcp [::1]:80->[::1]:63014: wsasend: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine